# Is there a command to deny an IP

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, apache-httpd

Looking at the access log I found excessive access from an IP address. I then edit either .htaccess or .conf files to deny access from that IP. I wonder if there is a command or a oneliner that can do the job, such as `deny 1.2.3.4`.

Or please show me how to insert a line `deny 1.2.3.4` in to the .conf file at certain line number, and then restart apache.

Added: My Joyent's instance does not have `iptables` command but IPF instead.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to add this to the `iptables` in order to block an IP:

`iptables -A INPUT -s <ipaddress> -j DROP`

Per the man pages:

`DROP` means to drop the packet on the floor.

Comment: Probably `-I` rather than `-A` in case there's an `ACCEPT` already in the chain.

Comment: I will update my answer as soon as I can

Comment: The problem is my Joyent's instance does not have iptables command but IPF (or ipfilter). I don't know enough IPF but if you give me a hint I would explore more. Thank though.

Comment: Adding the distribution to your question would be very helpful. I will look up the commands for iy

Answer (score 1):

First you have to edit your `ipfilter` config file in `/etc/ipf/ipf.conf`.

For instance add:

```
block in from src.ip.addr to dest.ip.addr
```

where `src.ip.addr` is the one you want to block and `dest.ip.addr` is you public IP address (you should be able to put `any` here).

You can test your setup with `ipfstat -io`. Just be sure that the `ipfilter` service is enabled. If you don't know how, you can look in you favorite search engine or open a new question (don't forget to mention your OS).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with blocking on IP is the person on the attacking end will just move to another IP, if they're intent on attacking your IP.

The fail2ban facility is extremely effective at blocking IPs, so IPs block for certain periods of time + then unblock.

This ensures if you incorrectly block an IP by accident, it will eventually unblock.

Using fail2ban solves the problem that attackers only use an IP for a short time, then the IP returns to a free pool. If this IP is then allocated by a "real" site + you've added a manual block, no traffic will flow to this new "real" site.

Manually blocking one IP is likely okay + I've seen some people with 1000s of IPs blocked over time.

Using fail2ban puts maintenance of what's a evil/good IP on auto pilot.